# How to Integrate the SMS Gate way for asp.net standalone application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sms-gateway

I've developed stand alone application using asp.net. I need to integrate the sms gateway for my app. How to add ?

Answer (score 1):

1. you need a gateway (account) to send sms like [vianett](http://www.vianett.com) (for
   example)
2. there are a example how to implement the API [Code example c#](http://www.vianett.com/en/developers/api-code-examples/c)